# getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 Extjs and SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

I'm using Extjs4 and SpringMVC in a web application.
I have a view called detail.js which contains a textfiled. (Of course that i have a store, model js (which concerns extjs) and a java model, o DAO, DTO and Service layers ...)
My problem is in my Js controller : i have a button to which i listen to a click event, when it's clicked, the controller launch the following methode :

```
saveCampagne:function(){
        var form = this.getDetail().getForm(); //here i get my form
        var me = this; //me contains the current controller
        if (form.isValid()) { //test if there is no errors in my form
            form.submit({
                url: 'saveCampagne.aspx',//the action mapped in my java class
                jsonSubmit: true,
                controller: me,
                success: function(form, action) {
                    alert("suuuuuuuceeeeessssss");

                },
                failure: function(form, action) {
                    alert("failure");

                }   
            });
        }
    }
```

In the springMVC side, i have the following method :

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCampagne")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> handleSaveCampagne(@RequestBody final CampagneDto campagne,final HttpServletRequest request){        

        LOGGER.debug("========= Save campagne called ");
        campagneService.insertCampagne(campagne);//calling service layer which calls DAO layer
        return buildJsonResponse(campagne);
    }
```

But my problem is that when i click on the button, i have the following error and i don't know from where it comes :(

getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415  (Type de Support Non Supportï¿½)

the sentense between () means some think like "Unsupported media type"

Any help ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turn your Spring logs to debug. It'll tell you what's up.

Comment: it does not even get to java side !! i'v tried to add some break points de JAVA side, but finnaly i discovred that it does not arrive there !

Comment: It  most definitely does get to the Java (server) side, otherwise you wouldn't get a 415, you would get a connection error. Spring is generating the 415 because some exception occurred while trying to parse your request body to generate an argument for the `@RequestBody` annotated parameter. Please do what I've asked and post the corresponding stack trace.

Comment: Actually you were right :) it does get to the server side.
The problem was there because in my DTO, i had a collection of class X which is self (The class X) contains an other collection of the class Y which was not serialisable !! 
This is the reason why i had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :)
It was in my DTO. In my DTO a hade a collection, but my Json send a string.
So there is no explicit conversion from string to collection.
What i did is that i redifined my setter, so it will take a string as a parameter and not a collection, then inside the setter code, i set a list of DTO elements that i've created basing on the string reseived.